# Publishing over 6000 messages to SNS from a lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a script that we wanted to run in AWS as a Lambda, written in Python. This will run once ever 24 hours. It describes all the ec2 instances in an environment and I'm checking some details for compliance. After that, we want to send all the instances details to an SNS topic that other similar compliance scripts are using, which are sent to a lambda and from there, into sumologic.  I'm currently testing with just one environment, but there is over 1000 instances and so over 1000 messages to be published to SNS, one by one. The lambda times out long before it can send all of these. Once all environments and their instances are checked, it could be close to 6000 messages to publish to SNS.

I need some advice on how to architect this to work with all environments. I was thinking maybe putting all the records into an S3 bucket from my lambda, then creating another lambda that would read each record from the bucket say, 50 at a time, and push them one by one into the SNS topic. I'm not sure though how that would work either.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: I don't see how it takes more than 15 minutes to send more than 6000 SNS messages, what is your timeout and memory setting?

Comment: Probably each SNS msg is triggering a Lambda and thus total concurrency reaches more than 1000 , hence the timeout

Comment: @Maurice Before sending the messages to SNS he needs to read details from a 1000 EC2 instances using the SDK. So There are a lot of queries going on in addition to the SNS requests. AFAIK SNS publish does not support batching. So if you write your code wrong, I guess it can easily timeout even with 900 seconds timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use Step Functions for this problem. Even if you fix the issue for now, sooner or later, with a rising number of instances or additional steps you want to perform the 900 second maximum runtime duration of a single Lambda won't be sufficient anymore.

---

A simple approach with Step Functions could be:

**Step 1**: Create a list of EC2 instances to "inspect" with this first Lambda. Could be all instances or just instances with a certain tag etc. You can be as creative as you want.

**Step 2:** Process this list of instances with a [parallel step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html) that calls one Lambda per instance id.

**Step 3:** The triggered Lambda reads the details from the provided EC2 instance and then publishes the result to SNS. There might already be a pre-defined step for the publication to SNS, so you don't need to program it yourself.

With the new [Workflow Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-step-functions-workflow-studio-a-low-code-visual-tool-for-building-state-machines/) this should be relatively easy to implement.

**Note**: This might not be faster than a single Lambda, but it will scale better with more EC2 instances to scan. The only bottleneck here might become the Lambda in Step 1. If that Lambda needs more than 15 minutes to "find" all the EC2 instances to "scan", then you need to become a bit creative. But this is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could you a SQS queue to solve you problem.

From SNS send the message to a SQS queue. Then from the SQS you lambda can poll for messaged ( default is 10 but you can decrees it though cli ).